# Is ionic storage preserved on ios when an updated version of an app is published

Tags: ionic-framework, storage

I have seen some posts that mention problems with ionic storage when publishing app updates. I'm using the @ionic/storage module in an ionic 5 app for ios to store some user customized app data. My question is will the user's data be preserved after they receive the app update?
I looked through the documentation but i couldn't find any information on this topic. Has anyone successfully updated an ios app and saw that the data managed by ionic storage was preserved after the update?

Answer (score 2):

Here info from documentation of `@ionic/storage` for `Ionic 3` (https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/storage/):

> When running in a native app context, Storage will prioritize using
> SQLite, as it's one of the most stable and widely used file-based
> databases, and avoids some of the pitfalls of things like localstorage
> and IndexedDB, such as **the OS deciding to clear out such data in low
> disk-space situations**.

The newest docs (https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-storage):

> Out of the box, Ionic Storage will use IndexedDB and localstorage
> where available. To use SQLite for native storage, see the SQLite
> Installation instructions.

So, to keep your data safe you should add SQLite to your application.